# Portrait mode gets misinterpreted as landscape when keyboard is on

Tags: android, ipad, mobile, web-applications

I am developing a web application targeting tablets and mobiles. The system is designed to be usable, thus landscape mode as well as portrait mode must be both supported. So, when the user changes orientation my web application will fire some events to rearrange the page accordingly.

### Portrait mode is misinterpreted as landscape when keyboard appears

Here is the problem. In all pages of my web application there is the search control consisting in a textbox and a button. When I am in portrait mode and click on the textfield, the keyboard shows and the viewport size changes having `height < width` which causes my application to go landscape while the device is in portrait. When the user leaves the focus from the field, the keyboard disappears and the portrait mode is correctly recovered back.

[image: The problem explained]

Take a look at the picture up here: when the user searches something, the landscape mode is activated. Why? Simple: Because the viewport has changed due to the keyboard showing and the final viewport has a height lower than width.

[image]

Without the keyboard on, we have `Height1 > Width1`, but when the keyboard is on we have that `Height2 < Width2` but having `Width2 = Width1`.

### All devices involved

As you can imagine, this is a problem actually involving all devices:

- Android
- Apple iOS
- Windows

devices.

Do you know how to fix this problem? What type of approaches is it possible to take to target such a scenario?

Answer (score 3):

an Excert from https://web.archive.org/web/20160509220835/http://blog.abouthalf.com/development/orientation-media-query-challenges-in-android-browsers/

> To solve the twitchy keyboard problem, we need to replace blunt
>   catch-all terms like ‘portrait’ with an aspect ratio that captures our
>   weird keyboard edge case.
>
> From above, we know that the screen dimensions of the Droid Razr, in
>   portrait orientation, with the keyboard displayed, are 360px by 253px.
>   Divide 360 by 253 and you get 1.4 (rounded to the nearest tenth).
>   While we could just write an aspect ratio media query like
>   min-aspect-ratio: 360/253, that’s a little too specific to one device.
>   So instead we’ll use 13 to 9. That also equals roughly 1.4 but it’s
>   easier on the eyes.
>
> For landscape media:
>
> ```
> @media screen and (min-aspect-ratio: 13/9) { /* landscape styles here */}
> ```
>
> And for portrait media:
>
> ```
> @media screen and (max-aspect-ratio: 13/9) { /* portrait styles here */}
> ```

Comment: +100 you saved my life without needing to dig much into it, thank you so much!

Answer (score -1):

It also depends how are you getting current orientation, Are you using Sensor ? Result may differ from physical orientation and screen proportions

Comment: No, I am simply getting the viewport size and I am basing all on that... so what do you mean using the Sensor? Please consider that that is a web application so I have only Javascript...

Comment: Sorry I missed that part with web application, What about Popup keyboard that will apear at bottom of screen so that it won't change your window dimensions.

Comment: Mmmmh, what do you mean by popup keyboard? Probably it is something I do not know about, and how to trigger it from javascript or html?

Comment: It can be element initialy set to invisible in css display:none or other property that will make it invisible and can be placed on bottom of your application's UI when user focus text box then for example via JavaScript set it to visible so it won't make your content's container smaller but it will apper on top of it thus it won't change size. Only problem may be if you wan't to add many entry fields on bottom of page, then popup may just cover them and user wont be able to see it, but i suggested that popup solution because on pictures attached i assumed your app will be kind of search engine